# How to increase FPS on YOLOv3

Tags: python, real-time, object-detection, yolo, object-detection-api

I'm a newbie in DL/Real Time Object Detection area and trying to learn some stuff from Youtube. Now my problem is I'm trained a model for real time object detection with using yolov3 in google colabrotary. Now I have `yolov3_training_last.weights`  `yolov3_testing.cfg`  `classes.txt` files for real time object detection. I'm using a python file for it but it gives me 2-3 fps while using my laptop camera. Is there any way to imporve my fps? I'm thinking its using my CPU for real time feed. How can I switch it to GPU? As I said I'm newbie in this area if there is any way, can you explain me how can I do it. If not can you tell me alternative ways to training a model for real time object detection please? I will be appreciated if you can help me. Thanks in advance...

My GPU: GTX1650

My CPU: Intel Core i7 9750H

My python file here:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

net = cv2.dnn.readNet('yolov3_training_last.weights', 'yolov3_testing.cfg')

classes = []
with open("classes.txt", "r") as f:
    classes = f.read().splitlines()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(100, 3))

while True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    height, width, _ = img.shape

    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1/255, (416, 416), (0,0,0), swapRB=True, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    output_layers_names = net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames()
    layerOutputs = net.forward(output_layers_names)

    boxes = []
    confidences = []
    class_ids = []

    for output in layerOutputs:
        for detection in output:
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            if confidence > 0.2:
                center_x = int(detection[0]*width)
                center_y = int(detection[1]*height)
                w = int(detection[2]*width)
                h = int(detection[3]*height)

                x = int(center_x - w/2)
                y = int(center_y - h/2)

                boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                confidences.append((float(confidence)))
                class_ids.append(class_id)

    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.2, 0.4)

    if len(indexes)>0:
        for i in indexes.flatten():
            x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
            label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
            confidence = str(round(confidences[i],2))
            color = colors[i]
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), color, 2)
            cv2.putText(img, label + " " + confidence, (x, y+20), font, 2, (255,255,255), 2)

    cv2.imshow('Image', img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key==27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

By default OpenCV's `dnn` module does not run on GPU, and hence, your model is likely running on CPU.

A simple way to increase throughput is to look at Model Optimization, like Quantization and Pruning. There are several ways of doing the same, some of the popular optimization methods are linked below.

There are a few optimizations that can be done to improve the Model Throughput (FPS):

- Optimize for **Intel CPU** using [OpenVINO](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/openvino-toolkit.html):

  - Official Documentation: [YOLOv3 to Intel OpenVINO conversion](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.2/openvino_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_convert_model_tf_specific_Convert_YOLO_From_Tensorflow.html)
  - Project using Intel OpenVINO: [Real Time Face Anonymizer](https://github.com/animikhaich/Real-Time-Face-Anonymizer)
- Optimize for **Nvidia GPU** - OpenCV's `dnn` Module:

  - PyImageSearch Blog: [OpenCV `dnn` with NVIDIA GPUs: 1549% faster YOLO, SSD, and Mask R-CNN](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/02/10/opencv-dnn-with-nvidia-gpus-1549-faster-yolo-ssd-and-mask-r-cnn/)
- Optimize for **Nvidia GPU** - TensorRT:

  - Convert YOLOv3 Weights > [ONNX Runtime](https://onnx.ai/) > [TensorRT](https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT)
  - [Blog: TensorRT Conversion for YOLOv3 pre-trained](https://jkjung-avt.github.io/tensorrt-yolov3/)
  - [Blog: TensorRT Conversion for YOLOv3 custom-trained](https://jkjung-avt.github.io/trt-yolov3-custom/)
  - [TensorRT Conversion Demo Source Code](https://github.com/jkjung-avt/tensorrt_demos#yolov3)

Each of these involves some amount of learning curve. Unfortunately, There is no easy way out.

Comment: Hello sir. If I'm not wrong I trained my model with Tesla T4 GPU and I have GTX1650 GPU in my local laptop. When I try to run this script I'm thinking that its running with using my GPU. Not CPU.

Comment: I'm not the professional in this area but I'm thinking using GPU will provide better results right?

Comment: If you have a GPU, then it will provide better results. I was not aware that you have a GTX 1650 GPU. In that case, yes, my answer would vary. I'll update my answer for the same. 

Also, to answer your question, OpenCV's dnn module does not run on GPU by default. You can refer to this for the same: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/02/03/how-to-use-opencvs-dnn-module-with-nvidia-gpus-cuda-and-cudnn/

Comment: I checked my fps in real time feed and its 2 or 3. I'm thinking that when I run this python file its running with my CPU. My GPU cant be that bad right? I got Intel Core i7 9750H CPU on my system.

Comment: What can I do for running it with GPU?

Comment: @YapayZeka, I've Updated the Answer to provide the required information to run on GPUs. You can follow the links for details.

Comment: Appreciated sir.

Answer (score 0):

For working with GPU first of all you should install CUDA and CUDA enabled Opencv to your computer. After you finished you should change this part of your code

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNet('yolov3_training_last.weights', 'yolov3_testing.cfg')
```

to this

```
net = cv.dnn.readNetFromDarknet('yolov3_testing.cfg', 'yolov3_training_last.weights')
net.setPreferableBackend(cv.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
net.setPreferableTarget(cv.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA)
```

For installing CUDA and OpenCV i suggest this video :

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YsmhKar8oOc&t=173s